# FileNotFound exception while loading applicationContext

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

I have an application that is using the [Spring Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework). And suddenly I started to get an exception on server startup. The exception is as follows:

```
ContextLoader E org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
   Context initialization failed
   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
   IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource
   [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is
   java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource
   [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
```

But I surely have this file in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/ folder. I'm using IBM [WebSphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_WebSphere) and on a server startup I get this exception. If I just redeploy my application (I'm working in [IntelliJ IDEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA)) - no exception caught.

It's worth to add that I started get this exception suddenly. I did not change my configuration files.

How can I fix this problem?

Here is my `web.xml` file:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Comment: What is your classpth?

Comment: @Renjith,on a System.getProperty("java.class.path") I get \WEB-INF\lib

Comment: After building, can you check whether you have applicationContext.xml included in class path?

Comment: @Renjith, after building this file is in /WEB-INF directory

Comment: Can you just provide the folder structure of your application?

Comment: src
-main
--java
---packages
--resources
---propery files
--webapp
---pages
---resources
---templates
---WEB-INF - xml config files here

Comment: check if you have all dependencies about spring with the same version

Comment: @Jaiwo99, as I said - I did not change anything. It worked well 5 hours ago and now,suddenly,it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just checked out the application list on my IBM WebSphere application Server and figured out that another application was giving this exception.